# jruby issue iterating over multi dimensional hash object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, jruby

So being new to rails I seem to be stuck on creating a loop within a loop to process the information.

I am getting:

> can't convert Symbol into Integer line #11

The line in question is:

```
Host <%= servicedetails[:hostidn] %> - <%= servicedetails[:status] %>
```

And here is the full version below. Being new Im clueless and open to suggestions.

```
<div>
<% @service_hash[:service_list].each do |servicesinfo| %>
        <ul>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <h2><%= servicesinfo[:service_name] %><h2>
                </li>
                <% servicesinfo.each do |servicedetails| %>
                <li>
                    Host <%= servicedetails[:hostidn] %> - <%= servicedetails[:status] %>
                </li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>

        </li>
        </ul>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

the JSON equivalent of this hash is

```
{"status":"successful","service_list":[{"service_name":"oozie","status":"RUNNING","status_message":"Running Master Service","host":"1"},{"service_name":"single-namenode","status":"RUNNING","status_message":"Running Service","host":"1"},{"service_name":"single-database","status":"RUNNING","status_message":"Running Service","host":"1"},{"service_name":"datanode","status":"RUNNING","status_message":"Running Service","host":"1"},{"service_name":"secondarynamenode","status":"RUNNING","status_message":"Running Service","host":"1"},{"service_name":"web","status":"DEAD","status_message":"Running Master Service","host":"1"},{"service_name":"tasktracker","status":"RUNNING","status_message":"Running Service","host":"1"},{"service_name":"jobtracker","status":"RUNNING","status_message":"Running Master Service","host":"1"}]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already iterating over the array of hashes with service info (renamed to make sense):

```
<% @service_hash[:service_list].each do |service_info| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Iterating over `service_info` would return `[key, value]` pairs--likely not what you want.

Access the information from `service_info` directly, as you already do with `:name`

```
<%= service_info[:host] %> - <%= service_info[:status] %>
```

I don't see anything called `:hostidn` in that hash, just `:host`; not sure if that's a typo, or if you're expecting additional data not shown.

Comment: the hash shown was representation I have since changed the output to reflect hostidn for other reasons, didnt notice it though when posting here

Comment: Side note still need to iterate over each set independently. This list is only a small version. I need to build up each container respectively with matching data for each container. Right now this is me trying to sort it out and figure out how to work with it.

Comment: @chris That's fine, as long as you know what you're actually getting. IMO it's more typical to iterate using `.each { |key, value| }`, or get the keys in the order you want and retrieve map values, but perhaps this works for you. In any case, in the version you show you'll get an array back, not a hash, which is why you get the error: it's expecting an array index, not a symbol.

Comment: I can work with that. I think I'd be more happy if I can get it to work as an array. Cause the output visually is something in the end thats going to be manipulated heavily by jquery just getting the output to resemble what I want initially seems to be the difficult part for me.

Comment: Is there a way to take the hash upon the view loading and convert it strictly to an array, and if so how would I work with the array properly

Comment: @chris You can explicitly convert a hash to an array of `[key, val]` arrays using `to_a`. Still not convinced that's what you really want.

Comment: Well then aside from the above. How would you suggest I work everything over? can you give a better example? Sorry. I feel so dumb founded by rails currently that its just frustrating the xxxx out of me. Cause I had this working another way via a JSON output and strictly javascript/jquery and now its gotta be rewritten to please the client desires

Comment: @chris I'd do it exactly the way you showed it, but correctly--I don't understand the issue with doing it like this.

Comment: Im starting to think I cant do what I need to via rails, this is insanity. I need to take this sample hash where the service list can have upwards of 200 more things in it, that will be sortable via hostidn, or service type.. theres only 6 service types currently and I can have results that are 200+ large, where theres 40 in one host, 10 in another and I need those services blocked together by host.. or I can have 50 of the same service, 20 of another and need to have them blocked together by the service.. the example I have above is only a single version of a 200+ set. can't get it right.. ay

Comment: @chris I don't see what Rails has to do with it; Ruby is Turing-complete just like JavaScript, and substantially cleaner. Sorting and grouping by arbitrary criteria is trivial; there are functions for both that take closures to define the sort order and grouping. If you're having an issue with something different, open a new question specific to that--the original question has been answered; if it wasn't what you really wanted to ask, start over.

Comment: yea Im gonna have to do that, I had the wrong idea of what I needed to do with this. I know its not just rails, but rails itself is just frustrating me right now. I could wiz through this with PHP, I could wiz through just just json and javascript. But with Rails Im am at a complete loss despite it and php being so damn close, and despite logic being similar across all languages to handle this. Rails is my Kryptonite

Comment: @chris It's difficult to help when the problem isn't articulated well. Compared to PHP, Ruby is a dream--if you contact me directly I'll try to walk you through whatever issue you think you're having.

Comment: I'd be more than happy to as I would like to figure this out. How would I go about contacting you directly?